# Alterar a visibilidade dos campos de um layout em tempo de execução

Tags: android

Em um layout para cadastro de clientes, existem os campos específicos para Pessoa Jurídica e Pessoa Física.
O controle do tipo de cadastro é feito por `RadioButton` que estão dentro de um `RadioGroup`.

Precisava que, ao selecionar o `RadioButton` de Pessoa Física, os campos referentes a Pessoa Jurídica não ficassem visíveis na tela e vice-versa.

Estou tentando alterar a propriedade `Visibility` dos campos para `gone` quando uma opção é marcada, mas não está acontecendo nada.

É possível realizar esse controle através dos `RadioButton`?

Segue código do `RadioGroup`

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgTipoEmpresa);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                boolean rbFisica = R.id.rbFisica == checkedId;
                boolean rbJuridica = R.id.rbJuridica == checkedId;

                if (rbFisica){
                    etCNPJ.setVisibility(2);
                    etInscricao.setVisibility(2);
                    tvCNPJ.setVisibility(2);
                    tvInscricao.setVisibility(2);
                }

                if (rbJuridica){
                    etCPF.setVisibility(2);
                    etRG.setVisibility(2);
                    tvCPF.setVisibility(2);
                    tvRG.setVisibility(2);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não utilize valores explicitamente quando existem constantes definidas para o efeito.
A classe ***View*** declara as seguintes constantes, a serem usadas no método `setVisibility()`, para definir a sua visibilidade:

```
View.VISIBLE    // valor 0
View.INVISIBLE  // valor 4
View.GONE       // valor 8
```

Ao utilizar as constantes evita erros e torna o código mais legível.

```
etCNPJ.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

No seu código você utiliza o valor 2 que não é um valor válido. ([Ver documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)).

Não esqueça também que, quando é selecionado um `RadioButton`, além de tornar *"GONE"* os itens que não se aplicam a essa situação terá de tornar *"VISIBLE"* os itens que se aplicam.

Uma forma simples de inverter a visibilidade é utilizado o operador `^` (XOR):

```
etCNPJ.setVisibility(etCNPJ.getVisibility() ^ View.GONE);
```

Após a execução desta linha `etCNPJ` tornar-se-á *VISIBLE* se estava *GONE* ou *GONE* se estava *VISIBLE*.

Comment: Perfeito. Eu acabei por confundir o `setVisibility` com o `android:visibility`.